# aspectj-maven-plugin 1.11 : missing tools.jar issue with jdk 11

Tags: java, maven-plugin, aspectj, java-11

I have aspectj-maven-plugin:1.11 in my pom and jdk 11 installed on my system. Jdk 11 doesn't have tools.jar in lib directory. This is causing maven build to fail with error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
> org.codehaus.mojo:aspectj-maven-plugin:1.11:compile (default) on
> project groundtruth-storage-writer: Execution default of goal
> org.codehaus.mojo:aspectj- maven-plugin:1.11:compile failed: Plugin
> org.codehaus.mojo:aspectj-maven-plugin:1.11 or one of its dependencies
> could not be resolved: Could not find artifact
> com.sun:tools:jar:11.0.7 at specified path ...\Java\jdk-11.0.7/../lib/tools.jar

How to solve this issue?

There is an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48173963/maven-aspectj-plugin-fails-to-build-with-java-9-due-to-missing-tools-jar), but that is more than 2 years old.

Comment: The issue is pretty much the same, right? Did the solutions suggest there not work for you?

Comment: It didn't  work.

Comment: You have tried both [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52277056/1746118) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49474325/1746118)? Since the version that you are using is itself 2 years old.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Update II (2023-03):**
The MojoHaus `aspectj-maven-plugin`'s development seems to have stalled again. Instead, the AspectJ developers recommend switching to a [different fork](https://github.com/dev-aspectj/aspectj-maven-plugin) of the AspectJ Maven plugin, which is kept up to date with AspectJ itself. The fork's coordinates are:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>dev.aspectj</groupId>
  <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.13.1</version>
</dependency>
```

**Update I:**

The official `aspectj-maven-plugin` has been resurrected, version 1.14.0 supports JDK up to 16.

**Original answer:**

Unfortunately, (as of July 2020) the currect version of the "official" `aspectj-maven-plugin` runs only on Java 8. There are two outstanding issues for it [here](https://github.com/mojohaus/aspectj-maven-plugin/issues/41) and [here](https://github.com/mojohaus/aspectj-maven-plugin/issues/24) and several PRs fixing them, but the maintainers haven't responded to any of them.

You can try switching to a different fork of the plugin, for example, [Nick Wong's version](https://github.com/nickwongdev/aspectj-maven-plugin):

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.nickwongdev</groupId>
  <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.12.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Yes, this is kind of the "official unofficial" version. Nick is trying to become the maintainer of the Mojohaus plugin, but everything is super slow there. His fork is even supported by IntelliJ IDEA now and automatically recognised in the latest few 2020.x versions. In Eclipse the situation is not so nice yet. See also my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62213003/1082681).

Comment: Issues are closed since may 30 2021 : https://github.com/mojohaus/aspectj-maven-plugin/issues/41#issuecomment-851062721