# Missing artifact com.sun:tools

Tags: java, maven, bamboo

**My issue:**

I am having an issue building a project on my bamboo agent.

The build works fine on my development server - i have recently migrated to using bamboo to build and test this application. However, i am encountering the following error:

```
07-Feb-2024 11:36:14    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:aspectj-maven-plugin:1.11:compile (default) on project app-name: Execution default of goal org.codehaus.mojo:aspectj-maven-plugin:1.11:compile failed: Plugin org.codehaus.mojo:aspectj-maven-plugin:1.11 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact com.sun:tools:jar:11.0.8 at specified path C:\Program Files\Amazon Corretto\jdk11.0.8_10/../lib/tools.jar -> [Help 1]
```

**What i have tried/think:**

I have installed the correct JDK needed on my bamboo agent - i have also copied over the tools.jar from the development server corretto 11 lib folder and onto my bamboo agent (this didn't work) and i am still getting the error.

One thing to note is that Corretto 11 isn't set as the JAVA_HOME - it is using JRE 1.8 since this was required for the bamboo remote agent to work. Could this be my problem? unsure on how i would fix that if so?

Kinda struggling on what to do - any help is appreciated

**Answer:**

I managed to get my answer from here

[aspectj-maven-plugin 1.11 : missing tools.jar issue with jdk 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62976155/aspectj-maven-plugin-1-11-missing-tools-jar-issue-with-jdk-11?rq=2)

Comment: Check for most recent version of aspectj maven plugin https://www.mojohaus.org/aspectj-maven-plugin/

Comment: thanks for this - helped me get my answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [aspectj-maven-plugin 1.11 : missing tools.jar issue with jdk 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62976155/aspectj-maven-plugin-1-11-missing-tools-jar-issue-with-jdk-11)

Comment: yeah if you look at my updated post - i tagged this link. thanks for taking a look